# Does Firefox devtool support breakpoints on XHR requests and DOM changes?

Tags: debugging, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I surprised that [Chrome devtool supports breakpoints on XHR and DOM changes](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints).

I can't find [corresponding features in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger).

Are they absent in Firefox?

**UPDATE** I found that [Firebug has such features](https://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html). But article dated by 2010 and I don't know if Firebug still in use instead of build-in Web Developer Tools.

Answer (score 2):

After digging in Firebug blog I found [that Firebug codebase will be moved to Firefox Developer Tools](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/02/08/merging-firebug-into-the-built-in-firefox-developer-tools/) due to upcoming Firefox **e10s** feature. FireBug 2.x can't work with e10s enabled.

So we should expect requested features in Firefox in future though it may require several years to implement.

Till that time I am going to use Firebug.

Note that Chrome is more flexible for setting XHR breakpoint because it allow filtering on URL substring, Firebug only on full preexisting URL ((